# how does _spf work on a DNS level?

Tags: email, smtp, spf

i have noticed that google and other domains use _spf for their domain. i would like to how this works.
would _spf be an a record that has multiple IP that would account for all mail servers or does this work in a different way?

Comment: i have a an understanding of SPF but i guess i would like to know how google use their SPF for multiple ip addresses?

Answer (score 1):

SPF, or Sender Policy Framework, starts with the idea that the owner of a domain controls the DNS, and so allows information in the DNS to be used to authenticate whether the origin of a mail message is one listed as expected by that owner.

A lot more information is available [here](http://www.openspf.org/).

It has been adopted fairly widely, but neither universally nor rigorously.

Its implementation is much as you suggest; it is an explicit or implicit (e.g. referring to the MX records) of IP addresses which should be sending mail for that domain. There are numerous modifiers described in the standard best read from links in the above.

Edit: I should also add that DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) is a related and somewhat newer technology, [here](http://www.dkim.org/).

Comment: i have a an understanding of SPF but i guess i would like to know how google use their SPF for multiple ip addresses: txt lookup on google.com = 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'. txt look up on _spf.google.com = 'v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all'. txt look up on _netblocks.google.com = 'v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all' what would the DNS records look like in this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps dense as I have not had breakfast, but those are the DNS records, so I am unclear what question are you asking?

Comment: i have 4 ip address that i am sending out from, and i would like to add an SPF record so its clean: i could add: v=spf1 ip4:123.123.123.1 ip4:123.123.123.2 ip4:123.123.123.3 ip4:123.123.123.4 ~all. But i would like to know how google add their records so its a clean: v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com ~all? - i hope this makes better sense.. i am starting to confuse myself.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I understand.  Google is adding them as blocks, so they add a very large number at one time,  They also did an include so as the first spf record was shorter, but implicitly it really contains the list.  For four IP's, you could possibly use a block, but it is not all that helpful.  If your four IP's are also inbound email MX records you can just refer to them with the MX code.

Comment: Thanks Linwood, sorry its hard for me to get my head around. Maybe what i mean is, if you can one have 1 SPF record per domain, how can google have have multiple SPF records, for their domain? maybe the first TXT entry is hostname 'blank' and the TXT is 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all' and there is another TXT entry with hostname '_spf' and the TXT for that is: 'v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all'.... and so on, if that would work, i think i have answered my own question.

Comment: If that was that case, i may have answered my own question.

so if this is the google way my DNS would look like this:

hostname: 'blank' TXT: v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com ~all
and another entry:
hostname: '_spf' TXT: v=spf1 ip4:123.123.123.1 ip4:123.123.123.2 ip4:123.123.123.3 ip4:123.123.123.4 ~all

Comment: Yes (+/- what you mean by "blank" as it's the root domain), but really, you are trying to hard.  Just list them, or better yet if they match the MX records use that.  One record for such a short list means one DNS fetch, not two.  There are lots of online SPF test sites as well, to test syntax, meaning, actual SPF's, etc.  Google is your friend.

Comment: i guess i am going into it more than what i need to, really i just need TXT: v=spf1 ip4:123.123.123.1 ip4:123.123.123.2 ip4:123.123.123.3 ip4:123.123.123.4 ~all. but i was trying to workout how companies use _spf.domain.com, as i have seen this a few times. i think it all makes sense now. thanks for your help / advice Linwood!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I dont know if this ansewer is exactly correct but here goes-

I think way google use their SPF records is as follows:

i have done a TXT lookup on google and followed some TXT records:

txt lookup on google.com = 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'. 
txt look up on _spf.google.com = 'v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all'. 
txt look up on _netblocks.google.com = 'v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ~all'

hostname: 'blank' TXT: 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all' 
hostname: '_spf' TXT: 'v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all'
hostname: '_netblocks' TXT: 'v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ~all'

If that is that case, i could add the following to my domain to be able to send from these IPs 123.123.123.1, 123.2, 123.3 and 123.4 using domain.com as the 'from' address.

hostname: 'blank' TXT: v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com ~all and another entry: 
hostname: '_spf' TXT: v=spf1 ip4:123.123.123.1 ip4:123.123.123.2 ip4:123.123.123.3 ip4:123.123.123.4 ~all

and an TXT lookup on domain.com would show: v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.com ~all

please let me know if this is incorrect logic.

Regards, Lee